# Quick question about baby Rudin: Theorem 2.40.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $I$ be a $k$-cell consisting of points $\bf x$ with $a_j\le x_j\le b_j$.
>
> $$ \delta :=\left (\sum_1^k(b_j-a_j)^2\right )^{1/2}$$
>
> Then $|x-y|\le \delta \forall x,y \in I$.$\cdots$
>
> Let $c_j=\frac {a_j+b_j} 2.$ Then the intervals $A_j=[a_j,c_j], B_j=[c_j,b_j]$ determine $2^k$ $k$-cells whose union is $I$... Take one of these $k$-cells and call it  $I_1$, continue subdividing these $k$-cells to get $I\supset I_1 \supset \cdots \supset I_n\cdots$.
>
> **Then $|x-y|\le 2^{-n}\delta, \forall x,y \in I_n$.**

I don't understand how to come up with the last inequality, could someone explain it? (I drew pictures and 'see' it in the cases $k=1,2,3$, but don't understand how to prove the general statement).

Also, whats a rigurous way to prove that the union of the determined $k$-cells is equal to $I$?

Comment: Geometrically, $\delta$ is the length of the longest diagonal of the $k$-cell, i.e. the "space" diagonal.

Comment: Try writing $\lvert x - y \rvert$ using the coordinates of $x$ and $y$. Note that each term of the resulting sum is less than the corresponding term of the sum for $\delta$. Note that the inequality for $x,y \in I_n$ follows from the first inequality since $I_n$ has side lengths that are $2^{-n}$ times the corresponding side length of $I$, and so we can get a new $\delta_n$ for $I_n$ using the first formula. We see $\delta_n = 2^{-n} \delta$.

Answer (score 5):

$\delta$ is the distance between far corners of the original $k$-cell $I$. Let $\delta_n$ similarly be the distance between far corners of $I_n$. Each subdivision halves the previous $k$-cell in each dimension so:
$$\delta_n = \left( \sum_1^k (2^{-n}(b_j - a_j))^2 \right)^\frac{1}{2} = 2^{-n} \left( \sum_1^k (b_j - a_j)^2 \right) = 2^{-n}\delta.$$
It is easy to see that $\delta_n$ is the largest possible distance between two points in $I_n$ - two points can't get farther than if they differ by the maximum possible amount in each dimension. The inequality:
$$|x-y| \le 2^{-n}\delta$$
merely expresses this fact.